# Creating and running tests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I created a unit test in my solution using the *Unit Test Wizard*: I selected the class and all its methods and properties, then the wizard has created a new file with a test method for each class method to test.

Obviously, the tests should be reliable, that is, a test should fail only if module does not work as expected and not because of a test poorly built. So the first question is: *what guidelines should be followed to build the test?*

In creating my first tests, I'm trying to write simple test cases, thus reducing the probability of errors: for example, to test a collection you need to add some element to it, so I created a private method like the following within my test unit:

```
// This is not a test method, but a support method for the test methods.
private void AddSomeElements(ICollection c, int count)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    ...
    for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
        c.Add(...);
}
```

So, for example, the test for `Count` property could be:

```
/// <summary>
///A test for Count
///</summary>
[TestMethod()]
public void CountTest()
{
    HostsCache target = new HostsCache();
    AddSomeElements(target, 100);
    int actual;
    actual = target.Count;
    Assert.AreEqual<int>(100, actual);
 }
```

Is this approach correct?
Suppose that the `Add` method returns a value (for example a `bool` value): in this case, should the above private method also return this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule 1: Don't try to boil the ocean.  Test only a small section of code at a time.  For unit tests, try to minimize external dependencies and interactions. This includes not spending time verifying that the core operating system is working, and core classes provided by the .NET framework, for example.  It's good to test that your code interacts with these external things correctly, but keep in mind that your focus is on testing the code you wrote, not on testing everybody else's code that your code uses.

Making sure that all the parts work well together is the job of integration testing, which is a very different testing scheme from unit testing.  Integration testing often requires different tools and different tactics from unit testing, and ultimately has different objectives from unit testing.

If you are writing your own implementation of the standard ICollection interface, then you should unit test your collection implementation.  Otherwise, you don't need to test that calling ICollection.Add() on a stock collection class provided by .NET does what it's supposed to do.

If your class uses a collection internally and exposes methods that manipulate the contents of that collection, one approach is to use only the public methods of your class to cause the class to change its internal state, and only use the public methods to see the effect of that action.

However, in many situations the internal state may not be fully exposed through public methods.  You can poke the object, but you can't really see exactly what happened inside.  Abstraction is good for system design because it hides implementation details from the consumers so that the details can be changed in the future as needed while maintaining the same the public interface and semantic contract.  Hiding internal details is good for system resiliency and longevity, but creates barriers for testing.

In such situations it is useful to enable some sort of hook or interface to the class to allow your tests to take a peek at the internal state. This does make your tests more tightly bound to the implementation details (change the code, and you'll have to change the tests too), but it also enables your tests to make much more detailed assessments of whether public actions are having the desired effect on the state of the object, particularly when the object deliberately obscures that internal state.

One example of such an internal access hook is the InternalsVisibleTo attribute in .NET.  You declare in your production assembly that it's ok for your test assembly to access class members declared with "internal" visibility.  Something you might automatically declare as private can be nudged up to internal to make it visible to your unit tests.  The data is still protected from normal clients.

Another term you should look up is the use of "mock" classes in testing.  A mock is a fake class that provides a minimal implemention of an interface or type required by the code being tested, and is used to isolate the code you're interested in testing from external code that you're not interested in right now.

For example, if the code you're testing calls a web service, it will be difficult to fully test all the many ways that a web service call can fail - time outs, connection refused, dns resolution failure, etc etc.  Swapping in a mock web service interface allows your test suite to manipulate the data provider that your code under test relies upon.  You're not testing the data provider, you want to test how your code responds to errors, bad data, and good data returned by the provider.  So mock the provider and control that data yourself in the test suite.

Answer (score 5):

One of the biggest mistakes that I have seen when writing tests is forgetting to treat the tests as first-class code.  That is, factor them in such a way that they are easy to maintain and modify as your application (and, by extension, the test) evolves.

The second biggest mistake I have seen is covering too much code in each test.  Each test, ideally, should test only a few lines of code.  Definitely no more code than what is contained within a single method.

So, if it makes sense for `AddSomeElements` in your example to return something, have it return something.  If not, don't.

Just remember two things:

1. Your tests are first-class code
2. Every test should only test a very small piece of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You should perform some simple tests on adding and removeing elements.

There is nothing wrong with the helper function that adds a set number of random elements, and then verifying the Count property as your test.  I would not bother with returning any other value from it - if Add fails by returning false then the helper function should throw an exception to make it clear where the error occured.

The boolean return value should be tested separately.

eg
1) create a collection and add an element, then assert that the collection does contain one element.
2) create a collection and add an element, assert that the element you put in is the same one you get out
3) if the add method returns a bool then checking scenarios for Add returning true and Add returning false should be two more test cases.

Comment: I would never write a test for functionality provided by the framework. I have a reasonable expectation that the `Add` method is adding elements properly.

Comment: I agree there is no need to test framework functionality - however the OP did include the words "to test a collection" and passed in ICollection, my assumption was that they are testing their own implementation of ICollection.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have not explained well, but but my goal is to test my collection. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly open-ended question but here are a few opinionated suggestions to get you on your way.

Each test generally has three parts to it.

a)  Arrange - Set up the values to send to the method your going to test, creating a verifiable and reproducible environment.
  b)  Act - Call your method or whatever your testing
  c)  Assert - Make sure your method did what it was supposed to, meaning it returned the right value or effected the correct side effect.

As a matter of taste, I put three comments delineating these sections //Arrange //Act //Assert

Arranging can sometimes be tricky if your method is not setup to be "testable".  Start looking into the wealth of information out there on Dependency Injection.  Once you make your stuff testable, there are tools out there like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), or [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page-d), or [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks.ashx) that can help.

On another note, I see you have a method that loads random data into a collection.  Tests should rarely have any randomness in them.  You don't want your test passing one day and failing the next if nothing but time has changed.  Fill your data with constants you choose and keep them that way.  To test different data, load different data.  Don't let the test do it for you.

I've just touched on a couple of points.  There's tons of information out there about how to test code.  The best way is just to start writing tests, and learn as you go.  Tests are better than no tests, and good tests are better than bad tests.

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood your question initially, my apologies.

It's perfectly reasonable to create a `TestHelpers` class or project to contain reusable code for helping you write your tests. For example, if you're operating off of sets of test data, you may create a few methods to get `GetSampleTestDataForScenarioX`, where "ScenarioX" is a descriptive name for your scenario.

Unit tests in general should contain very little in the way of branching or looping. I follow the Arrange/Act/Assert model of testing, where you start off by arranging the test (instantiating objects, setting up test conditions, etc), then act on the test data, then assert that my conditions are satisfied.